# make a new structure tag that does some processing

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

my goal is to have short urls. I'm trying to use base_convert so that "site.com/p=10000" becomes "site.com/7ps"

My code is such a mess I don't even think it would be helpful to post it. It's not doing anything I want.

I want to create a new structure tag named "%shortest_permalink%" .  In the wordpress settings permalinks page, I would like it to show up with the other structure tags.

Then, I could set it to site.com/%shortest_permalink%/

I would like %shortest_permalink% to be created by taking the post_id and changing it to a base 36 using

```
$shortened_id = base_convert($id,10,36);
```

and when the url is called, I want it to be translated back to call the post id

```
$id = base_convert($shortened_id,36,10);
```

I'm finding pieces of things, but I can not wrap my head around how to do it properly. I could rewrite urls, but that doesn't seem like the way to do it since the structure tag is available.