# How to make my custom permalink pull up the correct post

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm tryin to make short urls. Using base_convert, I can change site.com/10 to site.com/a

I'm currently using this...

```
function shortest_permalink_make_url( $url, $post, $leavename=false ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        $temp_id = $post->ID;
        $shortened_id = base_convert( $temp_id ,10,36);
        $url = str_replace($temp_id,$shortened_id,$url);
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'shortest_permalink_make_url', 10, 3 );
```

It works. site.com/a is generated

**what doesn't work:**
When I go to site.com/a it gives me a 404. How do I make wordpress know that site.com/a is supposed to bring up the post with ID of 10?

I was hoping this would work...

```
function shortest_permalink_translate_url( $wp ) {

    $shortened_id = $wp['p'];
    $temp_id = base_convert( $shortened_id ,36,10);
    $wp['p'] = $temp_id;
    return $wp;
};

add_filter( 'request', 'shortest_permalink_translate_url');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make a new structure tag that does some processing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/415559/make-a-new-structure-tag-that-does-some-processing)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried hitting the "Save" button on your permalink settings page to refresh it and apply the new rules?

Comment: Thank you, yes. This did not fix it.